# Area under distributions defined by $p(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}-a}$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

I've been watching 3Blue1Brown's livestream, specifically the one about power towers. I was playing with the inverse function of this system, $x^\frac{1}{x}$, and noticed that it's able to create a very interesting family of distributions by modifiying the function to $x^{\frac{1}{x}-a}$. Additionally, it seems that these functions all have finite area on $[0, \infty]$. I had a few questions about these distributions:

1. Do they have a name?
2. Is it possible to find the area in terms of $a$ so it can be normalized? I.e., can we find $g(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\frac{1}{x}-a}} \ d x$?
3. What value of $a$ gives the minimum area, and what is that area? I.e., can we find $b$ s.t. $g'(b)=0$ and compute $g(b)$? Playing around in Desmos suggests we might have $b=e$, but it's not close enough to be sure.
4. If we normalize our original function using the answer to 2. and treat it like a probability density function, what is the expected value of $x$?

Here's my Desmos playground: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7ayroajui4

Comment: It seems like there MIGHT also be a finite area for negative $a$ as well. Not sure, though!

Comment: There is not a finite area for negative $a$ because $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{1/x - a} = \infty$ for $a < 0$.

Comment: Also it seems that the minimum is approximately $a = 2.695$, not $a = e$, although this difference might be just noise with numerical integration.

Comment: Since $x^{1/x - a} > 1/x$ if $0 \le a \le 1$, the integral only exists for $a > 1$.

Comment: @VVejalla thanks for clarifying the negative case!

Comment: @VVejalla I didn't realize you made all three comments, was going to respond one at a time. I also assumed that the difference from $a=e$ was due to numerical integration noise. After thinking of $ln$, I also agree with your third comment. Thanks for all the clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

NOT A FULL ANSWER
$$\int^\infty_0 x^{\frac{1}{x}-a}dx$$
substituting $u=\frac{1}{x}$
$du=-\frac{1}{x}dx$, $dx=-x^2du$
$$\int^{0^+}_\infty -u^{-u+2-a}du$$
$$\int^\infty_0u^{-u}u^{2-a}du$$
we do know that
$$\int^1_0x^{-x}dx=\frac{1}{1^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}...$$
which could help us solve it for a=-2:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^n} + \int^\infty_1x^{-x}dx$$
if we want to find for which a the integral diverges a good check is:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x^{\frac{1}{x}-a}$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{ln(x)(\frac{1}{x}-a)}$$
$e^x$ is a continuous function
$$e^{\lim_{x \to \infty}ln(x)(\frac{1}{x}-a)}$$
little bit of product ruling later,
$$e^{-\infty a}$$
which tells us it converges for $a>0$ and unintegratable to infinity for a=0
when looking at the function's graph, it's obvious it has a maximum for some a.
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^{\frac{1}{x}-a} = -x^{\frac{1}{x}+a-2}(ln(x)-ax-1)$$
from this we get two 0's (0,a) and ($-\frac{W(-ae)}{a}$,a)
W - lambert W function.
The second one is the maximum of the function.(a<0)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer: A few questions:

1. When you substitute $u$, shouldn't the negative exponent be distributed? i.e., shouldn't $a$ be positive?

2. Doesn't $e^{-\infty a}$ mean it CONverges for $a>0$? Thanks again.

Comment: 2.correct. very correct. 1.no it shouldn't, i believe.